# How can I use scribe-java to insert new file to Google Drive

Tags: oauth, scribe, google-drive-api

Recently, I am trying to integrate Google Drive into my application using scribe-java(https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java).
and listing files/ get file by Id methods work fine. but I cannot get insert new File method work properly.
here is my code(insert):

```
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                .provider(GoogleApi.class)
                .apiKey("[my api key]")
                .apiSecret("[my api secret]")
                .scope(SCOPE)
                .callback("[my callback]")
                .build();
Token token = new Token(accessToken, accessSecret);
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files");
service.signRequest(token, request);
Response response = request.send();
```

This will create a "untitled" named file in my google drive, my question is how to upload my file from local file system and specify a name? since I tries adding adding body parameters, adding headers, they all not working. Many thanks

Comment: what does the documentation ask you to do? in what format should you send the file contents to google drive?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an "untitled" named file because you are not sending any content with your POST request.
You can find more information about the media upload protocol for the Google Drive API from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads).

Here is an example showing the protocol for the multipart upload method:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart

Authorization: Bearer <Access token>
Content-Length: 44332
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="===============0124852474844509178=="

===============0124852474844509178==
Content-Type: application/json

{'title': 'My Image'}
===============0124852474844509178==
Content-Type: image/png

<Binary data removed>
===============0124852474844509178==
```

I am not familiar with Scribe, but you might want to try using the [Google APIs client library for Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) which abstract all the protocol interaction in strongly typed classes. The Google Drive API's [reference guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) includes code snippets using this client library.